# Heavy latency on port 80 for flask app in AWS elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a multi-container setup for AWS Elastic Beanstalk where the Dockerrun.aws.json is as follows:

```
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": 2,
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "searchindex",
            "host": {
                "sourcePath": "/tmp/somefolder"
            }
        }
    ],
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "name": "search",
            "image": "search_image",
            "essential": true,
            "memory": 55000,
            "mountPoints": [
                {
                    "sourceVolume": "searchindex",
                    "containerPath": "/usr/src/app/search",
                    "readOnly": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "flask_app",
            "image": "image_flask",
            "memory": 4000,
            "essential": true,
            "links": [
                "search"
            ],
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "hostPort": 5000,
                    "containerPort": 5000
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The setup contains:

- a search index
- Flask app: The app is a front to query the search index. NOTE:
  this installation does not use a `Nginx` server as the    WSGI for
  flask but the flask resident server.

When I map my flask server to port 80 changing the above configuration of my flask_app to:

```
"portMappings": [
                    {
                        "hostPort": 80,
                        "containerPort": 5000
                    }]
```

I get a lot of latency on this even when I generate a request locally from the server. But if I use my original conf and query port 5000 the response time is the expected `ms` response.

Here is my `.ebextension/bootstrap.config`:

```
option_settings:
  aws:autoscaling:asg:
    "Custom Availability Zones": us-west-2b

  aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration:
    InstanceType: 'r3.2xlarge'
    EC2KeyName: somekeys.pem
    RootVolumeType: "gp2"
    RootVolumeSize: "200"

  aws:elasticbeanstalk:command:
    Timeout: 3600

  aws:elb:loadbalancer:
    LoadBalancerHTTPPort: '80'
    CrossZone: 'false'

  aws:elb:healthcheck:
    HealthyThreshold: '3'
    Interval: '10'
    Target: TCP:5000
    Timeout: '5'
    UnhealthyThreshold: '5'

  aws:elb:listener:5000:
    InstancePort: '5000'
    InstanceProtocol: HTTP
    ListenerEnabled: 'true'
    ListenerProtocol: HTTP

Resources:
  AWSEBInstanceLaunchWaitCondition:
    Type: "AWS::CloudFormation::WaitCondition"
    Properties:
      Timeout: "3600"

  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup:
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3Auth:
          type: "s3"
          buckets: ["somebucket"]
          roleName:
            "Fn::GetOptionSetting":
              Namespace: "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: "IamInstanceProfile"
              DefaultValue: "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"

files:
  "/tmp/searchindex" :
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    authentication: "S3Auth"
    source: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/somebucket/seachindex.tar.gz

commands:
  01_unpack_index:
    command: mkdir -p /tmp/search
    cwd: /tmp
    ignoreErrors: true

  02_unpack_index:
    command: tar -xzvf searchindex.tar.gz -C search/
    cwd: /tmp
    ignoreErrors: false
```

I am trying to do a few things here which I am not able to accomplish:

1. Make 5000 the port which the load balancer checks for health.
2. Make 5000 the default port for the load balancer to hit for incoming
       requests.
3. Figure why port 80 has this insane latency when I map 5000
       directly to it. I won't have to do the above 2 points if we figure
       this one out.

I would appreciate your help.

**HACK OF A RESOLUTION:**

Made a Nginx reverse-proxy from 80 to 5000. No latency. I am going to leave this information here and not in the answer because it does not explain why is their latency in the first place. Anyone struggling with this can at least get there Apps working.